# I want to find missing number in the series given in textarea

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function cal()
    {
        var a = $('#no').val();
        var b = a.split('\n');

        var p = $('#pre').val();
        var s = $('#suf').val();
        // var c=" ";
        var j = 1201;
        for(var i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            var x = b[i].replace(p, "");
            x = x.replace(s, "");
            // c=c+","+x;

            if(j == x)
            {
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("show").innerHtml = x;
                i--;
                c++;
            }
        }
        // c=c.replace(' ,','');alert(c);
    }
</script>
```

here i am not getting only all numbers but not missing numbers.
Numbers has prefix and postfix like V1201/15. Before calculating i have removed those.
but the for loop can not calculate missing numbers.

Comment: In JS `<!-- ... -->` is not comment. Comment is `//` or `/* ... */`

Comment: no change...no output

Comment: Where are you calling `cal()`?  Look in the browser's error console. Are there errors there?

Comment: <input type="button" id="BtnCheck" name="BtnCheck" value="Check" onclick="cal()" />

Comment: Ok. What about the errors in the console?

Comment: dont know. i have to run it in notepad

Comment: have you tried logging any of your variables to the console? That should help paint a clearer a picture of whats going on...

Comment: I used alert. It is showing numbers with removed sufix and prefix. after that it is not showing minimum numbers.

Comment: You'd be making your life indescribably esyer if you used descriptive variable names

Comment: Your life would also be very much easier if you learned how to use the console.